# Does this C++ Class Leak Memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I was wondering if a class I made for a program would leak memory.

Here's my implementation,

BubbleSort.h has 3 private variables:

```
int arrSize = Array Size
int* intArray = Original Array
int* narr = Bubble Sorted Array
```

BubbleSort.cpp

```
#include "BubbleSort.h"

BubbleSort::BubbleSort(int size, int* arr)
{
    arrSize = size;
    intArray = arr;
    printf("BubbleSort();\n");
}


// Object Destruction
BubbleSort::~BubbleSort()
{
    free(narr);
}

int* BubbleSort::Sort() {
    int swap = 0;
    narr = (int*)malloc(arrSize * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        narr[i] = intArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < arrSize; j++) {
            if (narr[j] < narr[i]) {
                swap = narr[i];
                narr[i] = narr[j];
                narr[j] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    return narr;
}
```

And here's my main file

```
#include "main.h"
#include "classes.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    BubbleSort sort = BubbleSort::BubbleSort(size, arr);

    int* narr = sort.Sort();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d > %d\n", arr[i], narr[i]);
    }

    printf("Hello World.\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Would this program leak memory during operation?

When I ran the code I checked that the BubbleSort instance 'sort' was destroying and it was but that was only when the application had finished running. I am currently learning how to use `malloc()` and `free()` in my programming course and had some free time so I decided to make a Bubble Sort class and wanted to experiment with it! So I hope there isn't too many errors in the code (related to the use of pointers).

Comment: If you sort more than once, there's a leak. Note: You should be able to sort without allocating more memory. If you need to preserve the original, copy it and sort the copy because you'll get a more general sorting method. Note: This be C++. so you shouldn't be using `malloc`/`free` outside of a few edge cases.

Comment: Besides leaking, constructing then immediately destroying an instance of the class will result in an attempt to free unallocated memory, undefined behavior, and pretty much a guaranteed crash.

Comment: There really is no need to write a class to do bubble sort. A simple function is enough. In general use classes when you have something that needs to *maintain state* over some part of your programs lifetime.

Comment: When you think more about what a memory leak is (a *global* misfeature of an *entire program*), you understand that your question makes no sense: a class by itself cannot leak, only the entire program using it could (or not) leak. Memory management is not a local or modular feature (and that is why it is so difficult). Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can help, since they observe the behavior of an entire program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `malloc` and `free` unless you interface with C code. Try to avoid `new` and `delete` as well, since C++ has many simpler patterns that are guaranteed not to leak and are as fast. Think of `std::vector` and, if `vector` is not good enough, think of `std::unique_ptr<int[]> narr` with `std::make_unique<int[]>(size)`.

Your program does not leak and does not crash by pure luck. To avoid leaks your class should have a clear invariant regarding memory, and it has none. There is no way to know when `narr` has an invalid pointer, or when it points to memory that has to be freed. As a result the following leaks:

```
int arr1[size] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
BubbleSort sort = BubbleSort::BubbleSort(size, arr1);
int* narr = sort.Sort();
narr = sort.Sort();
```

And the following has undefined behavior (free over an uninitialized pointer):

```
int arr1[size] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
BubbleSort sort = BubbleSort::BubbleSort(size, arr1);
return 0;
```

The easiest way (and correct in 99.9% of the cases) to deal with this, is to define ownership. You decide up-front who owns what object. With `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` the language decides it for you. The language does not let you accidentally transfer ownership of `std::unique_ptr` without an explicit action on your part. If you make a mistake, the compiler will simply give you an error.

---

**Side note**: if you want to learn C++, when you come from C background, it might be easier to start with `malloc`, `free`, `printf`, and raw pointers everywhere. However, you should remember that this is not idiomatic C++. Sooner or later you must move to C++ idioms like RAII, classes that have clear ownership and invariant, and use C++ library instead of C.

Comment: There is no actual downside to using malloc and delete for primitives and there is no eqv to realloc if you use new. I wrote myself an RAII wrapper when it made sense.

Comment: @joshua, You mean malloc and free. The downside is that code evolves and eventually it won't be primitives. Then the constructors/destructors will not called by malloc/free, and you have either to use deleters with unique_ptr/shared_ptr, or write your own. Nothing too serious, but just another place where a tough bug may be introduced. Probability-wise, if you have many such places, then you will have memory related bugs in your code, which could be avoided. Anyway, I think that c++ could benefit from a `renew` operator, but it is difficult  to define one without breaking existing code.

Comment: How badly do you want renew? I think it can be made as a library function.

Comment: @Joshua to make renew workable, it has to incorporated into allocators and containers (so vectors will use it). It also has to be an operator, so that it will call copy constructors/destructors when memory moves. It also has to call default constructor/destructor to account for allocation size changes. A portable library can't know the current size of the memory block.

Comment: Template methods can call the necessary constructors and destructors. The allocator is cheaper to write than the actual implemtation of the library method. The only portability trouble is sbrk isn't portable anymore. (DOS provided it; Windows didn't.)

Comment: @Joshua memory (re)allocation is not just sbrk. First, you can't mix `new[]` with sbrk, because new[]/delete[] have additional book keeping (whose ABI is not standardized). Then allocation can be with sbrk or mmap (also not standardized). Then there are cases when realloc need not call any system call. For example, if allocation is implemented in chunks of 16 bytes, then growing a block by 4 bytes is likely change nothing (again a non portable detail). And don't get me started on the fine details of the free list and its variants. No portable library is possible.

Comment: It's certainly portable when you clobber the system's versions of malloc, realloc, free, new, delete. And yes, it's intentional that you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

This allocation pattern is very bad. Yeah the program you gave doesn't leak, but you will leak in bigger programs if you don't rethink your patterns.

Either allocate `narr` only in the constructor (RAII) or don't free in the destructor but in the calling function (old school) or get rid of the object altogether and pass `size` and `arr` to `sort()`.

Soon it will be wise to start using the standard template library, but that's a topic for another day.

As Sam Varshavick pointed out, if you create one of these is and don't call sort you crash in the destructor. Any of the methods I offered will fix this, as will initializing `narr` to `NULL` in the constructor.